# Not able to set checkboxes based on saved results from DB

Tags: angular, spring, spring-boot, checkbox

.ts File:
editUser(userData: user): void {

```js
let selectedProjectIdsList = userData.projectIds.split(',')

for (let i = 0; i < selectedProjectIdsList.length; i++) {
  this.projects
    .filter((x) => x._id == selectedProjectIdsList[i])
    .map((x) => (x.selected = true))

  console.log(
    this.projects
      .filter((x) => x._id == selectedProjectIdsList[i])
      .map((x) => (x.selected = true)),
  )
}
```

.html File:

```html
<ul class="list-group list-row">
  <li class="list-group-item" *ngFor="let item of projects">
    <input
      class="form-check-input me-1"
      type="checkbox"
      value="item._id"
      (change)="onChangeProject()"
      [(ngModel)]="item.selected"
      name="selected"
    />
    {{ item.projectName }} | {{ item.buName }} |`enter code here`
    {{ item.reporter }}
  </li>
</ul>
```

Note : After getting API response from backend It checked all the checkboxes

Comment: try binding to the checked property on the checkbox input element.

Comment: It is not working

 <input
                  class="form-check-input me-1"
                  type="checkbox"
                  value="item._id"
                  (change)="onChangeProject()"
                  [(ngModel)]="item.selected"
                  name="selected"
                  [checked]="item.selected"
                />

Answer (score 0):

1. If you're using a `[(ngModel)]` then you shouldn't be using `value` and vice versa.
2. Your `value` isn't binded with the variable, but with a string

-> this will always correspond to a `checked` checkbox, since the value isn't empty -> considered as "true"

```html
<input type="checkbox" value="item._id" name="selected" />
```

-> This will be bound with your variable, which will then show the checkbox according to the value of your variable. Then use your `onChangeProject()` to update your variable somewhere else.

```html
<input type="checkbox" [value]="item._id" name="selected (change)="onChangeProject()" />
```

-> This will automatically update your object

```html
<input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="item.selected" name="selected" />
```